# Convert object type in Func<>

Tags: c#, linq, repository-pattern

I have a repository object where I encapsulate my data store's data types. I have defined objects that are used throughout my application, and inside the repository, I have to map them to the types that the data store exposes. I have the following so far:

```
//The class object I work with inside my code
public class Class
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class ClassRepository
{
    public Class GetClass(Func<Class, bool> query)
    {
         //newQuery = Do something to convert the Class object in Query to internalClass exposed from Database
        using (var context = new DBEntities())
        {
            return Mapper.Map<Class>(context.InternalClasses.FirstOrDefault(newQuery));
        }     

    }
}
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to convert `Func<Class, bool>` to `Func<internalClass, bool>` so that I don't have to expose the object that the data resource uses to my code.

Comment: When you are posting code with angle brackets like your `Func<Class, bool>` be sure to wrap the text with a backtick ` (the key to the left of 1 on most keyboards), if you don't the website thinks you are trying to do a HTML tag and will strip it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using AutoMapper, don't use Mapper.Map with IQueryable objects. Use the [`QueryableExtensions`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) namespace instead with its `Project().To<T>()` method, it is designed for this exact situation.

```
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;

public class ClassRepository
{
    public Class GetClass(Expression<Func<Class, bool>> query)
    {

        using (var context = new DBEntities())
        {
            return context.InternalClasses.Project().To<Class>().FirstOrDefault(query);
        }    
    }
}
```

Also you should be passing in `Expression<Func<Class, bool>>` not `Func<Class, bool>` or your query will not happen server side. It will still work with `Func<Class, bool>` but you are going to be returning all rows over the network then performing the filter on the client in memory. This will give you very bad performance for large tables.

Comment: Thanks, how does Class become InternalClass though? - NM didn't get what was happening in the Project() part of your code.

Comment: That is just what `Project().To<T>()` does. AutoMapper creates the equivalent `IQueryable<internalClass>` object to your `Class` you passed in. If you want the details of how it works you will need to read the source of AutoMapper.

Comment: @Mike [Here is a article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code) by the guy who originally wrote the `QueryableExtensions` from before it was part of the project itself, the automapper guys ended up adding the code in the article to the project at a later date.